# Proper, RESTful way to design an endpoint for inexact filtering

Tags: rest, api-design

Say I have endpoints for GET `/objects/{id}`, GET `/objects/{code}`, and POST `/objects`, as prescribed by RESTful design, and `objects` have fields `name` and `code` (unique).

I want to consume the `objects` data in another app, particularly with autocomplete filtering on both `name` and `code`.

As I see it, the options are

- GET `/objects?q={user-input}` where `q` is what the user is typing, and the backend does a SELECT statement with `LIKE '%{user-input}%'`
- POST `/objects/search` with a JSON payload

Which is more RESTful? Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what my goal is.

If all my application does, beside "cruding" objects, is to search by autocomplete, and maybe some other fixed search, I would use a specific endpoint and action.

- `GET /objects/autocomplete?prefix=<>`

It may look strange, since this is at all not RESTful, but my point is to make a simple and specific endpoint, in case this is all your application is about.

But of course if the app needs to support more flexible filtering, I would choose a POST request with the filters in the payload.

- `POST /objects/search`

Both are not necessarily very RESTful, and in my opinion REST is not always the best strategy, more important is the use case. Anyway the object "cruding" and relations actions ARE (RESTful), so I would leave these untouched, this is why you may prefer `/objects/search` over just `/objects` (in both GET and POST), to make sure you don't affect the domain.

You can read more in depth here :https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/353086/what-is-a-proper-way-to-do-a-complex-restful-search-method